# Converting a 16-bit array containing 12-bit numbers in to an 8-bit contiguous array

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

My data is 12-bit and is stored in an array of 16-bit values. They're just values < 4095.

I need to output the 12-bit data in 8-bit chunks; top row are the 12 bits of the input values, bottom row is the 8 bits of the output values.

```
11|10|09|08|07|06|05|04|03|02|01|00|11|10|09|08|07|06|05|04|03|02|01|00
07|06|05|04|03|02|01|00|07|06|05|04|03|02|01|00|07|06|05|04|03|02|01|00
```

So for the output array:
The first byte contains the first 8 bits of the first 12-bit value.
The second byte contains the last 4 bits of the first 12-bit value and the first 4 bits of the second 12-bit value.
The third byte contains the last 8 bits of the second value.
And so on...

So ideally I want to turn an array of 12-bit numbers stored in a 16-bit array into an 8-bit array where the values are contiguous.

Technically it doesn't have to be out as an 8-bit array, I can output the 8-bit values through a function `SPI.Transfer(byte)` as I step through the 16-bit array.

Comment: `SPI.Transfer(byte)` does not sound like C. If you use the different language C++ or Arduino, use the correct tag.

Comment: Not withstanding references to (non-standard) `SPI.Transfer(byte)`, your question is ambiguous.  On one hand, you say you have a 16-bit array.   On the other hand, you say data is stored in bytes (which, on most but admittedly not all systems, are 8 bits).

Comment: @Olaf — that part is mildly irrelevant - it's in C. I just need to split the bit array into smaller bits and pass it to a function.

Comment: @Peter — I have edited and cleared up the language about how the data is stored — an array of 16-bit values — but I don't get where I say it was stored in bytes?

Comment: Are your numbers in little endian or big endian?

Comment: @Fabien - little endian

Answer (score 1):

So this works; maybe there is a more elegant way?

```
    byteCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOf16bitItems; i++) {
        if (i % 2) {
          //if odd then just grab the last 8 bits
          toArray[byteCount] = fromArray[i] & 0b11111111;
          byteCount++;
        } else {
           // if even get the first 8 bits and output, plus get the last 4 bits and the next bits of the next item
           toArray[byteCount] = (fromArray[i] >> 4) & 0b11111111;
           byteCount++;
           toArray[byteCount] = ((fromArray[i+1] >> 8) & 0b1111) | (fromArray[i] & 0b1111 << 4);
           byteCount++;
        }
      }
```

Comment: toArray[byteCount] = (fromArray[i] >> 4) & 0b11111111; you dont have to mask it. If toArray is a byte array then the assignment will just assign the 8-bit of 16-bit wide (fromArray[i] >> 4) value. Since your actual data is 12-bit wide, shifting 4 bits to right will give you "00h byte-your byte" and the assignment will take care "your byte" to your toArray.. toArray[byteCount] = ((fromArray[i+1] >> 8) & 0b1111) | (fromArray[i] & 0b1111 << 4); is one another way to represent what i've provided. So there's nothing new in your own answer actually. I could've got the loop definition wrong.

Comment: hi @The_aLiEn - I'm doing two things on the even array items — splitting off the first 8 bits and then taking the remaining 4 and adding them to the next 4. Thanks for the masking tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify endianness and the terms first and last. First from MSBit or LSBit? One way or another there will be lots of **shift**ing, **or**ing, **and**ing in bussiness. And your result data will be as in source format, endianness and first/last point of view.

Assuming first 8 bits are starting from most significant bit:

```
for(i = 0; i < Lenght_of_16_Bit_Array; i++)
{
  if(i % 2 == 0)
    i8 = a16[i] >> 4; // takes first 8-bit and chops least 4-bits
  else
    i8 = a16[i-1] << 4 | a16[i] >> 8 // takes least 4-bits of prior item and chops 8-bits of current item.

  a8[i] = i8;
}

// last control if your initial length is an odd number(means the index is even)
if(Lenght_of_16_Bit_Array % 2 = 1)
  a8[Lenght_of_16_Bit_Array] = a16[Lenght_of_16_Bit_Array - 1] & 0xF; //recover that last 4 bits
```

Comment: Thanks @The_aLiEn — this got me on my way

Comment: @user2929831 You're welcome. Just give proper voting and/or accepting the answer if it's "the" answer as this community mandates..

Comment: it didn't actually work, just got me thinking in the right way — see my solution above